# Rebasing program

Tags: ida

When I start debug in IDA, it's appears small window "Please wait... Rebasing program", and it's take about 3 minutes. Is it possible eliminate this process named Rebasing program? It take long time to wait.

Comment: Modern OS usually randomize the start address of a program using ASLR, that is why IDA has to rebase the loaded executable so that it matches the real addresses. You can try to configure the OS to not use ASLR on the process you want to debug.

Comment: This post explains exactly same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663139/rebasing-and-debugging